# Django getting superuser to use in a model class

Tags: django, superuser

I want to get all users information to set up user profiles including superuser, but somehow my code doesn't get superuser data . Please have a look

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Share your code where you are trying to get all users

Answer (score 0):

as per the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project), Instead of referring to User directly, you should reference the user model using django.contrib.auth.get_user_model(). This method will return the currently active user model – the custom user model if one is specified, or User otherwise. So use `User = get_user_model() or settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` if you a custom user